# MQTT Android Service not working while phone is locked

Tags: android, mqtt

I'm trying to create an Android service, which use a notification when the phone receives a MQTT message.

When the phone is locked, the service is not working and is not given a notification.

I have looked at the things to solve this, but they are very battery consuming. This is not what I want.

The idea is just like whatsapp of snapchat, they notifying me when I got a message.

Is a Android service the right solution for my problem? Or is something else better. And if the service is the right thing what do I exactly use.

This is what I have made already:

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.IntDef;
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttActionListener;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttSecurityException;

public class MQTTService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MQTTService";
    MqttAndroidClient client;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManger;
    int mNotificationID = 0;

   public MQTTService() {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int 
 startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand methode called");

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            initMqtt();
            Log.i(TAG, "start init");
            client.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {
                @Override
                public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {

                }

                @Override
                public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
//                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
"MQTT Message:\n" + new String(message.getPayload()), 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        notifyNotifications(topic, new 
 String(message.getPayload()));
                    }

                @Override
                public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {

                }
            });
        }
    };

    Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(r);
    backgroundThread.start();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy methode called");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public void initMqtt()
{
    Log.i(TAG, "start init");
    String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
    client = new MqttAndroidClient(this.getApplicationContext(), "tcp://192.168.2.128:1883", clientId);
    Log.i(TAG, "client created");
    try{
        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
        options.setMqttVersion(MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1);
        options.setCleanSession(true);
        client.connect(options, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                Log.i(TAG, "connect succes");
                subscribe();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                Log.i(TAG, "connect failed");
            }
        });
    }catch (MqttException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i(TAG, "connect failed exception");
    }
}

public void subscribe()
{
    String topic = "test_mqtt";
    int qos = 1;
    try{
        IMqttToken subToken = client.subscribe(topic, qos);
        subToken.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                Log.i(TAG, "subscribe succes");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "subscribe succes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                Log.i(TAG, "subscribe failed");
            }
        });
    } catch (MqttSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i(TAG, "subscribe failed exception security");
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "subscribe failed exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void notifyNotifications(String topic, String message)
{
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle(topic)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000,1000})
            .setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000)
            .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);

    Notification note = mBuilder.build();
    note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    mNotificationManger = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManger.notify(mNotificationID, mBuilder.build());
    mNotificationID++;
}
```

}

And ofcource a activity, which start the service:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        notifyNotifications("start", "start service");
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MQTTService.class);
        startService(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

MQTT will require persistent connection to the server which will inherently consume battery. MQTT will be better choice only if you want to subscribe to topic while UI is active.

Better option for you will be to explore FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging).

If FCM is not an option and you have to stick to MQTT, consider launching foreground service and deal with wake locks. I would still urge you to use FCM instead of MQTT with foreground service and wake lock.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it